# ASP.NET CORE Base class not working for some users on the hosting IIS server

Tags: asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET CORE MVC project, all app controllers inherit from a base class that has some common properties and a method that every derived class would implement.  Strangely, only certain users but not all would get the following error.  When executed, the code error out on the await next().  The code works fine on my development workstation using IISExpress or Kestrel.  Does anyone know why?

```js
o   MyProject.Controllers.BaseController.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) in BaseController.cs
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
o   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
•
```

Here is the base class

```js
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyProject.Models;
using MyProject_Model_CORELibrary;
using MyProject_Repository_CORELibrary.Contracts;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
  public abstract class BaseController : Controller
  {
    protected MyProjectContext RepositoryContext { get; set; }
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;
    protected IRepositoryAggregate _repoAggregate;
    protected int _currentFY;
    protected UserProfile _userProfile;
    protected readonly UserManager<CustomIdentityUser> _userManager;
    protected readonly SignInManager<CustomIdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public BaseController(MyProjectContext repositoryContext, ILogger logger, IRepositoryAggregate repoAggregate, UserManager<CustomIdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<CustomIdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
      this.RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;
      _logger = logger;
      _repoAggregate = repoAggregate;
      _userManager = userManager;
      _signInManager = signInManager;

      int currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;

      if (DateTime.Today >= new DateTime(currentYear - 1, 10, 1) && DateTime.Today < new DateTime(currentYear, 10, 1))
        _currentFY = DateTime.Today.Year;
      else
        _currentFY = DateTime.Today.Year + 1;

      _userProfile = new UserProfile();

    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
      VUserMapping thisStaff = null;

      //get user id from CORE UserManager
      ClaimsPrincipal principal = this.User;

      if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(principal))
      {
        CustomIdentityUser customIdentityUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (this.User != null && this.User.Claims.Count() != 0)
        {
          _userProfile.LastName = customIdentityUser.LastName.ToUpper();
          _userProfile.FirstName = customIdentityUser.FirstName.ToUpper();
          _userProfile.NetworkName = customIdentityUser.NetworkID.ToUpper();
          if (_userProfile.NetworkName.IndexOf('\\') != -1)
          {
            _userProfile.NetworkName = _userProfile.NetworkName.Split('\\')[1];
          }
          thisStaff = _repoAggregate.VUserMapping_Repository
            .FindByCondition(x => x.StaffNetworkId == _userProfile.NetworkName).FirstOrDefault();
          _userProfile.UserID = thisStaff.StaffStaffId;

        }
      }

      ViewData["Principal"] = this.User.Identities.ToString();
      ViewData["UserName"] = string.Format("{0} {1}", _userProfile.FirstName, _userProfile.LastName);
      ViewData["UserID"] = _userProfile.UserID;
      ViewData["FY"] = _currentFY;

      await next();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the shown stack trace, there are a few things that look suspicious. For instance, you are accessing properties of `customIdentityUser` without first checking if this object is null. Also, even if that object is not null, you are calling `ToUpper` and other string methods on those properties. Are those properties are guaranteed to be non-null? Is `_userManager.GetUserAsync` guaranteed to never raise an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ivan Vargas
Thanks for pointing out the null checking.  I had a typo in the code. Instead, it should be like below.

```js
      if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(principal))
      {
        CustomIdentityUser customIdentityUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (customIdentityUser != null && customIdentityUser.Claims.Count() != 0)
    {
      _userProfile.LastName = customIdentityUser.LastName?.ToUpper();
      _userProfile.FirstName = customIdentityUser.FirstName?.ToUpper();
      _userProfile.NetworkName = customIdentityUser.NetworkID?.ToUpper();
```

I have the following service in the startup.cs which prevents the user's Windows Identity from being detected.  The strange thing is that no matter the AutomaticAuthentication is on or off, in the host IIS server environment, the user Windows Identity is always null even I injected IHttpContextAccessor and tried to get it from the HttpContext.  When I completely removed that line, then everything works.

```js
 //services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.AutomaticAuthentication = false; });
```

When I published the project to the IIS server, the user principal form this.User is always null.